# Username is required error, even if I send username in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Passport and Laravel's Validator.

Here is my Login Controller:

```
public function login (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 422);
    }

    $user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();
    if ($user) {
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
            $response = ['token' => $token];
            return response($response, 200);
        } else {
            $response = ["message" => "Password mismatch"];
            return response($response, 422);
        }
    } else {
        $response = ["message" =>'User does not exist'];
        return response($response, 422);
    }
}
```

Here is my `routes/api.php`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ApiAuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'json.response']], function () {
    Route::post('/login', [ApiAuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [ApiAuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [ApiAuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

Here is the `request`:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/login
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "sundowatch",
    "password": "12345678",
}
```

But it returns this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Date: Sat, 24 Apr 2021 17:35:31 GMT, Sat, 24 Apr 2021 17:35:31 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.26
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57

{
  "errors": [
    "The username field is required.",
    "The password field is required."
  ]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps "$request->json()->all()" instead of "$request->all()"?

Comment: @Simon no, it's not working.

Comment: The controller doesn't receive the values, what is the value of $request->all()?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I will share with you some small tips for a clearer code, so don't take this as a bad critic, just a constructive one.

Use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` instead of `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`, you will be able to use `Validator::validate()` instead of `Validator::make()` and then `$validator->fails()`, doing so already removes at least 3 lines of codes and it is clearer.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Validator::validate($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
]);
```

This will throw an error (`ValidationException`) with all the data as you did (`errors => all errors`), and it will return `422`. So you can completely remove `if`.

```php
Validator::validate($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
]);

$user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();
if ($user) {
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
        $response = ['token' => $token];

        return response($response, 200);
    } else {
        $response = ["message" => "Password mismatch"];

        return response($response, 422);
    }
} else {
    $response = ["message" =>'User does not exist'];

    return response($response, 422);
}
```

You can still do `$validated = Validator::validate(...);`, and if it fails it will return with errors, but if it passes, it will **ONLY** store validated fields (`username` and `password` in this case, if user sent `is_admin = 1`, it will be ignored, so you will have `$validated['username']` and `$validated['password']`) so this prevents us from messing up using other non-validated inputs, let's say you forget to validate an input and you do `$request->is_admin`, so if you only use `$validated` you will for sure only used fields that are present in the `rules` part. For the moment, I will ignore this and continue using `$request`.

Then we can rearrange the `$user` and the next `if`. You can use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()`, doing so, you can then remove the `else` and just have a code without `if-else`. It would look like:

```php
Validator::validate($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
]);

$user = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))->firstOrFail();

if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
    $response = ['token' => $token];

    return response($response, 200);
} else {
    $response = ['message' => 'Password mismatch'];

    return response($response, 422);
}
```

Then, you can also change the last `if-else`. I recommend you to read about `If guard clauses` [here](https://codeinphp.github.io/post/replace-nested-conditions-with-guard-clauses/) and [here](https://engineering.helpscout.com/reducing-complexity-with-guard-clauses-in-php-and-javascript-74600fd865c7).

So, you can have it like this:

```php
Validator::validate($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
]);

$user = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))->firstOrFail();

if (!Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
    return response(['message' => 'Password mismatch'], 422);
}

$token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;

return response(compact('token'));
```

See that:

1. I have changed the `if` logic, thanks to `guard clause` we are inverting the clause, so we are only going to exit if what happened/have is not desired.
2. I have replaced `$response` directly with the value, I do not like creating values and then having them used in the next line when it will return that. (This is super personal, still see how we have reduced code a lot by doing so and it is still readable and understandable at first glance)
3. I have changed `$request->username` and `$request->password` with `->input('username')` and `->input('password')`. You can see source code for both and it is nearly the same, I just prefer to use `input` as I will understand that is 100% laravel, but if you do `->username` it could be something you have macroed or similar. Again, this is personal.
4. See that, for the last line, I have:

   - Removed `200` as it is the default value and will always be for `response`, no need to write it again, we know it is the default as it is a good response, no errors.
   - Replaced, again, `['token => $token]` but in this case with [`compact`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). This is again a personal choice, but using both ways is the same. I just wanted to change it so everyone that is not aware of `compact`, could learn it now and maybe use it in the future.

---

So, compare your original code with the new one, same functionality but smaller and more readable:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 422);
}

$user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();
if ($user) {
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
        $response = ['token' => $token];
        return response($response, 200);
    } else {
        $response = ["message" => "Password mismatch"];
        return response($response, 422);
    }
} else {
    $response = ["message" =>'User does not exist'];
    return response($response, 422);
}
```

```php
Validator::validate($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
]);

$user = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))->firstOrFail();

if (!Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
    return response(['message' => 'Password mismatch'], 422);
}

$token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;

return response(compact('token'));
```